# Ubuntu installer does not detect Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, usb-installation

I'd like to install Ubuntu Focal Fossa onto a new hard drive. On my computer, there is already another hard drive with Windows 7. However, the installer does not detect this installation. I'm pretty sure that I booted in UEFI mode:

```
$ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
UEFI
$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0006
...
Boot0006* UEFI: (FAT) Generic Flash Disk 8.07
```

I've tried different options in Rufus while creating the bootable USB stick, however, this doesn't help at all. Is there anything else I can do?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

After having started the installation in BIOS mode, the second Windows installation is recognized.

Clicking on "Something else" shows all available drives:

[image: existing partitions]

I would like to install Ubuntu on hard drive "sda". However, I cannot choose this hard drive when I select "Install Ubuntu alongside them". The drive "sdc" is the only option in the "select drive" drop-down menue:

[image: "select drive" drop-down menue]

Comment: `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` where did you run this command? In "try before installing" mode?

Comment: @AkashKarnatak Yes, I cancelled the installation when I saw that Windows hasn't been recognized, and run this command afterwards.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have BIOS. Can you confirm by following this guide for windows. https://www.easyuefi.com/resource/check-windows-is-booted-in-uefi-mode.html

Comment: @AkashKarnatak You're right, this was the problem. I was mislead by the fact that when booting, I could select an UEFI menue by pressing F12. I now booted Ubuntu Installer in BIOS and it detects Windows. If you put this as an answer, I will accept it. Based on that, I've got another question: Is there a way to install Ubuntu at another hard drive than Windows without having to add partitions manually? When I click on "install Ubuntu alongside Windows" it only offers me the Windows hard drive. Clicking on "Something else" it shows me all three hard drives that I have in my computer.

Comment: Did you reserve some unallocated space for Ubuntu installation? Also I'd be easier for me to help you, if you could share a screenshot of your disk partiotions

Comment: @AkashKarnatak I've inserted screenshots of the partitions and of the selection window. My aim is to install Ubuntu on the empty hard drive "sda". I thought Ubuntu would offer this selection in the drop-down menue after choosing "Install Ubuntu alongside them", but it doesn't. Do I have to partition the drive manually? If so, which partitions does Ubuntu need? I've read something about swap partition, home partition etc. Or would the root partition be enough?

Comment: Are you sure tha dev/sda is empty, installer shows ntfs file system on it?

Comment: @AnjaM yes manual partitioning would be better. BTW how much space do you want to allocate to Ubuntu? Also I'd be better if we move our discussion to a room

Comment: @AkashKarnatak I've just managed to install Ubuntu with manual partitioning according to the instructions posted by V.H. As you were the one who helped me with the original question, please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USE SOMETHING ELSE OPTION**

0. **ORIGINAL QUESTION**
   First you need to identify if Windows 7 is installed in UEFI or legacy mode. You can easily do this via BIOS settings or from Windows. Run `msinfo32.exe` from Regedit, which can be opened with <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Under System Summary you can find *BIOS MODE* line with exact mode of installation.

   Now you can proceed with installation. Depending on your PC/laptop you need to boot USB as BIOS mode (often named LEGACY mode on  newer PCs). Easiest option would be to disable UEFI boot in BIOS settings completely. You will not need it now, and if you ever need it, you can easily enable it again. That option is probably under BOOT section of BIOS settings (or something similar depending on manufacturer. Now when that part is completed, you can proceed with instructions.
1. Choose "Something else" on step 4 of Ubuntu install:

   [image: Step 4 — Something else]
2. You will see your disk as `/dev/sda`,`/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. You said that you want
   to install it on `/dev/sda`, so choose that device and press <kbd>-</kbd> to delete
   existing partition on it(`/dev/sda1`) **NOTE:** Make sure that you want to delete
   that partition, and if it contains some important data make a backup. If you want to
   resize it, use <kbd>change</kbd> option and choose new size of `/dev/sda1` so you can
   leave some room for other partitions.
   Click "New Partition Table..." Now you will see empty space for your Ubuntu
   installation:
   [image: free space]
3. *Recommended if you are low on RAM* Create swap partition, swap is the partition for
   keeping unneeded memory pages, like Windows swap. Also it can be used for
   hibernation. Note that swap is much slower compared to RAM, so too much swap can
   slower you system. Use following table for guidance:

   ```
     RAM   No hibernation    With Hibernation  Maximum
     1GB              1GB                 2GB      2GB
     2GB              1GB                 3GB      4GB
     3GB              2GB                 5GB      6GB
     4GB              2GB                 6GB      8GB
     5GB              2GB                 7GB     10GB
     6GB              2GB                 8GB     12GB
     8GB              3GB                11GB     16GB
    12GB              3GB                15GB     24GB
    16GB              4GB                20GB     32GB
    24GB              5GB                29GB     48GB
    32GB              6GB                38GB     64GB
    64GB              8GB                72GB    128GB
   128GB             11GB               139GB    256GB
   256GB             16GB               272GB    512GB
   512GB             23GB               535GB      1TB
     1TB             32GB              1056GB      2TB
     2TB             46GB              2094GB      4TB
     4TB             64GB              4160GB      8TB
     8TB             91GB              8283GB     16TB
   ```

[SOURCE: https://help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#:%7E:text=How%20much%20swap%20do%20I%20need%3F%20For%20less,available%20for%20the%20system%20because%20of%20diminishing%20returns.)

- Select free space and click <kbd>+</kbd>
- Set parameters like on the picture below:
  [image: Swap parameters]

4. Create partition for `/` (root partition). This is base partition which contains Kernel, system files, program files etc. So like `C` partition on Windows. You need about 20GiB for this partition, but you put more (if you have space) and if you need more in some time, you can simply extend it via [GParted live USB](https://gparted.org/).So:

- Select free space and click <kbd>+</kbd>
- Set parameters like on the picture below:
  [image: Root fs parameters]

5. Create  `/home` partition. This is the partition for your user's files, like documents, images, song, movies etc. So like `Users` folder on on Windows.

   You can do this just like in step 4.
6. *For advance users* You can probably skip this part, but I will still put it here. Create separate `/boot`, `/tmp` and `/var` partitions. For exact sizes of partition use this:

- `/boot`  100 – 500 MiB
- `/var` and `/tmp` should be > 5 GiB
  or modify these values according to your needs.

After all that, you should see your disk like this:
[image: Final disk layout]

**P.S.**
Also you asked about having separate `/` and `/home` partitions. Strictly speaking you don't need to. That is a question of personal taste, but having a separate `/home` partition would help you in case of errors during upgrade to new release of Ubuntu. There is always a small chance of some kind of error in system upgrade which can result in data loss.

That is it! You can now click on <kbd>Install Now</kbd> and start enjoying Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

By default Ubuntu 20.04(and 18.04 )'s live USB(made bootable using rufus) installs using UEFI mode. Therefore it is unable to detect drives in computer which uses BIOS. Installation mode can be switched by selecting `Boot from next volume` option in the GRUB menu followed by the required installation type.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've awarded the bounty to you as you were the first one to solve my original problem. I've accepted V.H.'s answer as it now also contains the answer to the original question along with additional useful information.